# Reference for the equivalence between chain complexes and sequential diagrams in a stable $\infty$-category

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, stable-homotopy, infinity-categories

Lurie's $\infty$-categorical Dold-Kan Correspondence relates simplicial objects and sequential diagrams in a stable $\infty$-category. Is there any reference for an equivalence to a category of homotopy chain complexes? That this equivalence holds is well-known, and I feel comfortable with the argument, but I'd like to save myself the trouble of writing it down and to give credit to whoever first did so. Actually I'm interested in cochain complexes, but that isn't important.

Specifically, I'm thinking of a homotopy coherent cochain complex as follows: let $\mathcal{P}_{fin}\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ be the poset of finite subsets of the positive integers. Call $S\in\mathcal{P}_{fin}\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ *orderly* if for all positive integers $n$, $n\leq \max(S)\implies n\in S$. A cochain complex in a pointed $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$ is a functor $$C:\mathcal{P}_{fin}\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\to \mathcal{D}$$ such that $C(S)=0$ whenever $S$ is not orderly.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the *dual* Dold-Kan correspondence? That's for cochain complexes and *co*simplicial objects. I think it was first written down in 2004 by Castiglioni and Cortiñas: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404903003025

Comment: @DavidWhite yes, but because the definition of stable infinity-category is self-dual, the two are equivalent, and either will work for my purpose :) Thank you for the reference!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01017 does what you want! The description of coherent chain complexes used there is a bit different than what you suggest, but they look equivalent at first glance.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!